# how to use rest-framework simple JWT package for custom user model?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have created a custom user model in Django. Now I'm authenticating with the below code.

```
class Login(APIView):

    def post(self,request):
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email= email,password=password)
        print(request.user)
        if(user is not None):
            print("Logged In")
        return Response("Hello")
```

But from the official documentation I can't find how to achieve this is usecase. They just use `TokenVerifyView.as_view()` in `urls.py` file. How to use JWT authentication with this custom user model.

Comment: you dont need to create any view for authentication. `TokenObtainPairView ` will authenticate and return the tokens. `TokenVerifyView` will verify if the token is valid

Comment: Yeah that's true. can you provide it as an answer?